# Mapping between the Poincare disk model and a negatively curved surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I am comfortable using the [Poincare disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) as a model of hyperbolic geometry, but it has left me with a question for which I don't have a good answer:

Is there a negatively curved surface that we could imagine the Poincare disk as representing?  Ideally there would be a reasonably nice way to transform this negatively curved surface into the Poincare disk (similar to how the [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) can be turned into the Poincare disk).

Note: When I say "negatively curved surface," I am looking for a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose metric induced by the Euclidean metric causes it to exhibit hyperbolic geometry, just as the sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ exhibits elliptic geometry.  (I'm under the impression that this will require the desired surface to have constant curvature, but I'm not sure about this.)

Comment: no, there is not. You can embed a small piece with constant negative curvature, but "full" pieces tend to have problems; the two I have in mind are surfaces of revolution and topologically tubes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere

Comment: Of course!  I had completely forgotten about that property of negatively  curved spaces.

Clarification question: So is constant curvature in fact required then to create the "desired surface"?  Or is that an unnecessary assumption?

Comment: Yes, constant curvature $-1$ and simply connected. It is easy enough t make Riemann surfaces that do this, but they do not sit nicely in R^3 ...   https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-compact-surfaces-with-constant-negative-curvature

Comment: The counterpart of the sphere in R^3 is the hyperboloid model, which is great except that it uses the Minkowski metric. Dini's surface yields an R^3 embedding of an arbitrarily large fragment of the hyperbolic plane, but you cannot see much (no wonder since the amount of space in radius r in hyperbolic geometry is exponential, so it is impossible to fit it so that you can see everything). Hyperbolic crocheting (or computer simulations such as hypersian rug at http://roguetemple.com/z/hyper/models.php ) gives a nice representation, but it is not given by a formula and not smooth.